# Minimal PDF file according to PDF-2.0 spec results in corrupted document structure

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I am trying to create a minimal PDF file example using the PDF-2.0 standard based on the ISO Specification. I would like to avoid using the Xref Table and use instead only the Cross-reference stream dictionary and no Trailer Section.

The file opens in Adobe, but when I want to close it, it tries to save it which I consider it does to fix what it is considering a corrupted document structure.

So I guess that my PDF to not comply with the PDF-2.0. But why not?

Here is my code for the PDF-2.0 File:

**UPDATE:**
I tried to follow some of the comments, thanks for these inputs. Update was:

- added Length on the XREF Stream as it seems to be required for a stream (strange in the example in the spec I see examples without Length, but ok added now). I didn't add (yet) page content as it is defined to be optional.
  The new version of the Pdf opens in Acrobat but when closing the save dialog still appears.

Still don't know what bit is missing to be reconized by Acrobat as valid file and no prompting any saving dialog.

```
%PDF-2.0
%Óëéá
1 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R
/Metadata 5 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R 4 0 R]
/Count 2
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type /Metadata
/Subtype /XML
/Length /2880
>>
stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
      <pdf:Producer>PdfProd</pdf:Producer>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
      <xmp:CreateDate>2024-02-28T23:46:34+01:00</xmp:CreateDate>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
      <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
      <xmpMM:DocumentID>f2015454-8669-45e4-9218-ad61ad0e2082</xmpMM:DocumentID>
    </rdf:Description>
  </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>

                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type /XRef
/Index [0 7]
/Size 7
/W [1 2 1]
/Root 1 0 R
/ID [<1f7139e82f1c048ff020a6c953c3addd><1f7139e82f1c048ff020a6c953c3addd>]
/Length 77
>>
stream
00 0000 00
01 000F 01
01 004F 02
01 008D 03
01 00D3 04
01 0119 05
01 0CAB 06
endstream
endobj
startxref
3405
%%EOF
```

**2ND UPDATE:**
I tried to implement all suggestions, many thanks for all the very useful and precious inputs in the comments. After these changes, the validation over some online pdf validation, say the file is ok. But it fact for Acrobat now it's even worse, when I try to open the file in Acrobat, is not able to open it anymore ("The file is damaged and could not be repaired."). Thanks in advance for any help!

```
%PDF-2.0
%Óëéá
1 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog
/Metadata 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type /Metadata
/Length 2881
/Subtype /XML
>>
stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
      <pdf:Producer>Pdf2You</pdf:Producer>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
      <xmp:CreateDate>2024-03-04T23:42:40+01:00</xmp:CreateDate>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
      <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
      <xmpMM:DocumentID>7525a6cc-24c0-4d27-a995-17ee0436f906</xmpMM:DocumentID>
    </rdf:Description>
  </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>

                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Kids [4 0 R]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
/Resources<<>>
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type /XRef
/Length 66
/Index [0 6]
/Filter /ASCIIHexDecode
/Size 6
/W [1 2 1]
/Root 1 0 R
/ID [<884dfb9a4ffe1d4accf3d4454478960f><884dfb9a4ffe1d4accf3d4454478960f>]
>>
stream
00 0000 00
01 000F 00
01 004F 00
01 0BE0 00
01 0C18 00
01 0C6D 00
endstream
endobj
startxref
3181
%%EOF
```

PS: the end of lines are all LF.
PPS: the validation tool saying is valid is https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx

Comment: Don't you need a `/Filter /ASCIIHexDecode` for your `/Type /XRef` stream? I'm just guessing.

Comment: Don't you need a `/Length ...` for your `/Type /XRef` stream?

Comment: Have you tried getting error messages from a PDF validator? (I don't know if there is a good one.)

Comment: In your cross reference stream you have the object number in the last column but you should have had the generation number there. As an aside, all the errors mentioned in the comments here, are not PDF-2 specific, they also would have been PDF-1 errors...

Comment: @pts: the specs says that Filter is optional for Streams and XREF Streams "are stream objects... and contain a dictionary and a data stream".

Comment: Of course **Filter** is optional. But if you don't want a filter than you should not hex-encode the data.

Comment: *"Still don't know what bit is missing to be reconized by Acrobat as valid file and no prompting any saving dialog."* - well, your cross references still are completely broken. Take the comments here seriously.

Comment: @mkl: actually you were right, I dind' take in consideration all the comments in my first version. Maybe I still miss something? As you can see from the 2nd update comment, Acrobat is now not able to open it anymore. So thanks again for any help.

Comment: @ermeglio *"the end of lines are all LF."* - are you sure? I copied & pasted the text like that into a file but the size of the stream object and, therefore, the offsets of all following objects are off by 39, the number of lines in your metadata. That diff may indicate that you used CRLF in the stream. Or it may indicate that some other characters got lost in transmission.

Comment: Ok, just as @KJ already hinted at, Acrobat appears not to like **ASCIIHexDecode** filters in cross reference streams. Thus, I took your new file, added whitespace to the metadata to make lengths and offsets fit, and then removed the xref **Filter**, decoded your hex-encoded xref data, and used a binary xref stream: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf4Mx.png - Acrobat is happy with that.

Comment: @KJ According to the spec there also is nothing that forbids using **ASCIIHexDecode** in a cross reference stream. Adobe Acrobat simply does not support the complete PDF standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am  showing the more common features of your file from 2.0 ISO Standard that will allow acceptance by most, if not all, version 1 or 2 PDF readers. Without them or Acrobat considering any "fix" on entry or exit.

The smallest possible with a "Trailer" and **acceptable to Acrobat** etc. is roughly 300 bytes (303 with preferred EOL after EOF).

```
%PDF-2.0
1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]>>endobj
xref
0 4
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000052 00000 n 
0000000101 00000 n 
trailer<</Size 4/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
164
%%EOF
```

Smallest with XrefStream and not "fixed" or "rejected" by Acrobat Viewer 6 or later is 371 bytes (perhaps 370 if you ignore the %%EOF EOL)!
[image]

```
%PDF-2.0
%ÞÐƒ²
2 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 4 0 R>>endobj
4 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 4 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]>>endobj
1 0 obj<</Type/XRef/Root 2 0 R/Length 10/Size 5/Index [0 5]/W [1 1 0]/ID [<0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF><0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF>]>>
stream
  ªk: 
endstream endobj
startxref
170
%%EOF
% The following hex table is a pictorial representation in HexCode of the streams
% 10 byte binary data hence we must include the binary 2nd line (%ÞÐƒ²) marker.
stream
00 00
01 AA
01 0F
01 6B
01 3A
endstream endobj
```

It does not matter which order each object is numbered and commonly metadata would be 3rd object, if an info section were at the first location. Acrobat will normally "fix" a PDF, by add a duplicate info section first, with entries selected from the metadata. However here for "minimal acceptable" to Acrobat conforming readers, there is no /Info section.

Note the standard says there does not "need" to be a metadata section, so that can be deleted and thus use a smaller example.

> It is not strictly the minimum acceptable because it contains a page content stream (Contents in the page object), and a metadata stream. These objects were included to make this file useful as a starting point for creating other, more realistic PDF files.

Usually the /Type is found as the last object entry while we may logically expect or preferer that first. Comments related to altering your version are at the end.

```
%PDF-2.0
%ÞÐƒ²
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Metadata 5 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/Contents 4 0 R/Resources<<>>>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 0>>
stream
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Metadata/Subtype/XML/Length 1059>>
stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
<pdf:Producer>name</pdf:Producer>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
<xmp:CreatorTool>name</xmp:CreatorTool>
<xmp:CreateDate>2012-12-25T12:34:56Z</xmp:CreateDate>
<xmp:ModifyDate>2012-12-25T12:34:56Z</xmp:ModifyDate>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
<dc:title><rdf:Alt>
<rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">title</rdf:li>
</rdf:Alt></dc:title>
<dc:creator><rdf:Seq>
<rdf:li>author</rdf:li>
</rdf:Seq></dc:creator>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
<xmpMM:DocumentID>GUID of document</xmpMM:DocumentID>
<xmpMM:InstanceID>GUID save change</xmpMM:InstanceID>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
 
<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
endobj
xref
0 6
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000075 00000 n 
0000000126 00000 n 
0000000220 00000 n 
0000000266 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 6/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
1401
%%EOF
```

### Alterations

Pages should include a `/Count`, even if it is single Page [0].
`<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>`

A page should infer some contents (even if we declare it is empty).
`<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/Contents 4 0 R/Resources<<>>>>`

A minimal page content can be acceptable as.

```
# # obj
<</Length 0>>
stream
endstream
endobj
```

Others have suggested an altered "xref" structure. However although the standard "HINTS" of the type you want (an expanded Cross-reference text stream). I have yet to see that documentation format acceptable by Adobe Acrobat. I have no examples, other than it be /FlateDecode encoded.

In the standard this is "hinted" as.

> /Filter /ASCIIHexDecode %For readability only
> data has been encoded in hexadecimal representation for readability; in actual practice, a lossless decompression filter such as FlateDecode can be used.

Adobe added an explanation in their 1.7 Reference, same appendix H, which seems to still be current policy.

> "3.4.7, “Cross-Reference Streams” (Cross-Reference Stream Dictionary) 20. FlateDecode is the only filter supported by Acrobat 6.0 and later viewers for cross-reference streams. These viewers also support unencoded cross- reference streams.

So commonly readers should/could use either fully flatted or fully inflated and never mix the two, especially when there are edits (incremental additions, alterations etc).

I have used the smaller (in this case 2.0 H2 example) with inflated text version above.

**[Later EDIT]**

As @mkl has pointed out your Xref table can be replaced without the ASCII /Filter by using a pure binary stream and all readers including Adobe Acrobat Viewers will accept that as an equivalent working format. **In effect it meets the "unencoded cross- reference streams" statement.**

so replace

```
5 0 obj
<</Type /XRef
/Length 66
/Index [0 6]
/Filter /ASCIIHexDecode
/Size 6
/W [1 2 1]
/Root 1 0 R
/ID [<884dfb9a4ffe1d4accf3d4454478960f><884dfb9a4ffe1d4accf3d4454478960f>]
>>
stream
00 0000 00
01 000F 00
01 004F 00
01 0BE0 00
01 0C18 00
01 0C6D 00
endstream
endobj
startxref
3181
%%EOF
```

With

```
5 0 obj
<</Type /XRef
/Length 24
/Index [0 6]
/Size 6
/W [1 2 1]
/Root 1 0 R
/ID [<884dfb9a4ffe1d4accf3d4454478960f><884dfb9a4ffe1d4accf3d4454478960f>]
>>
stream
       O à  m 
endstream
endobj
startxref
3181
%%EOF
```

Where the stream in ASCII terms will be including nulls a more compressed (compared to the decimal text values)
`0000000001000F0001004F00010BE000010C1800010C6D00`

However for pure ANSI editing that would be an unworkable method.

Most readers that allow it to open would simply replace that section as ASCII table for example replace 6 with 7

```
6 0 obj
<<>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Creator (\(FlexiPDF\))/ICNAppName (FlexiPDF)/ICNAppPlatform (Win)/ICNAppVersion (3.0.7)/ModDate (D:20240305155621)>>
endobj
xref
0 8
0000000005 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000223 00000 n 
0000003183 00000 n
.... etc.
```

or convert to flated stream

```
6 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 4/Predictor 12>>/Filter FlateDecode
/ID [<884DFB9A4FFE1D4ACCF3D4454478960F><884DFB9A4FFE1D4ACCF3D4454478960F>]
/Length 41/Root 1 0 R/Size 7/Type/XRef/W [1 2 1]>>
stream
xÚcb``øÏÄÈÀÏÈÄÀàÈ dma`úÏÝd}­`dúÏý Y:{
endstream
endobj
startxref
3167
%%EOF
```

PDF ISO Standard compliant readers (apart from Acrobat) will also consider this combination as meeting the standard so easier to use uncompressed by ISO 2.0 Compliant Readers however **NOT in Acrobat** !

```
/Filter/ASCII85Decode>>
stream
z!<<W1!<>mq!=Rfc!=TeF!=WfF
endstream
endobj
startxref
3181
%%EOF
```

The above compressed (5 bytes shown as one) ASCII 120% expanded string is acceptable to most readers (apart from Acrobat DC). Even Acrobat Powered plug-in within Edge will accept it !

Here Acrobat reader in Edge refuses to open the file.
[image]
Same File in same EDGE TAB simply switched from IE mode, so using lighter "Powered by Adobe Acrobat" plug-in it works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort K J, much appreciated, but it still has two issues (or at least how it seems to me):
1. if I open your file in Acrobat Reader (Version of Acrobat is Continuous Release 2023.008.20555 64 Bit) , the files open, but it's still showing the save dialog when trying to close.
2. it contains the XREF Table

Both points were basically the goal of my tries: having a minimal pdf file without XREF Table but using XREF Stream Data. And of course without having a save dialog when closing it.

Comment: But maybe Adobe Reader is not able to recognize it as a complete file? Therefore this brings me to a further question:

What is the minimal content for a Pdf 2.0 (or lower) in Adobe Reader not having a XREF Table and without compression and specially without having a Save Dialog?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @K J: thanks a lot for all the comments and the files, they were a very big help to achieve a successfull validation. Nevertheless after implementing the changes, the file can't be opened in Acrobat anymore. See my 2nd Update above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot @K J.
Just one point: how can I encode my numbers to get something like this:

stream
       O à  m 
endstream

Comment: Funny. I guess Adobe introduced xref streams in PDF-1.5 with the idea of using it with deflate and predictor 12 and only really implemented that while more generically describing it in the non-normative PDF Reference.

Comment: @K J thanks for the background information, after applying your advices the file is opened in acrovat and no save dialog appears, thank you very much.